# CodeEffects RuleEditor doesn't display enum values if they are stored in a list

Tags: c#, collections, enums, business-rules, codeeffects

I have updated [the code effects angular code example](https://codeeffects.com/Doc/Business-Rule-Implementation-Example-Core-Angular) with a property on Patient that contains a list of enums

```
    [Field(DisplayName = "Favorite food", Description = "The patient's favorite food")]
    public List<Food> FavoriteFood { get; set; }
```

Where the Food enum looks like:

```
    public enum Food
    {
        Sandwich = 0,
        Apple = 1,
        Banana = 2,
        Noodles = 3,
        Candy = 4
    }
```

When I create an execution rule that checks if the food list contains certain items, the values aren't displayed in the rule when the rule is saved.

[image: My rule looks like this]

And the way this is sent to the controller on save is:

```
If Favorite food contain  and Favorite food do not contain  then Register with a Message ("Give&nbsp;apples&nbsp;instead&nbsp;of&nbsp;bananas")
```

The rule xml is saved correctly and works as expected. We want to use the rule text as the description. How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the latest version of the Code Effects rule editor's script available [here](https://codeeffects.com/Public/Samples/Code/CodeEffects.txt). This should fix the inability of your editor to load/display values of the enums.

The decoded values in string params are a known issue and it's going to be addressed in the next minor version due for release next week.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of the editor and having the same problem, any other suggestion?